# How can I adjust background color of blendfile previews?

Tags: customization, blend-files, file-browser

Before Blender 2.74, the background of Blender files (not the 3D View, not the rendered picture, but previews in the Windows file manager) have matched the Horizon-Color setting in Blender Render (Properties>World>World>Horizon Color).

Unless you havent set camera on a fullscreen model or scene, all parts of the camera where nothing (no geometry/transparent space) is shown, appear in the color of this setting.

But with Blender 2.74 released, the background color went transparent for overwritten files, ignoring the Horizon setting.

- Is there a way to change the color again (without geometry)?

Comment: I would check File > User Preferences > Themes... Unless you were trying for something else. Sorry I'm on my tablet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [File] > [User preferences...]

Click the tab [Themes]

Select [3D view] on the list on the left

Scroll down to section [Theme background color] > [Gradient High/Off]

Click the color to choose a new one.